# Do I have to use API.AI to create an action for Google Home?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have some experience building chat and voice agents for other platforms, but I’m not using [API.AI](http://api.api) to understand natural language and parse intents. Do I have to replace my existing solution with [API.AI](http://api.api)?

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. The advantages of using [API.AI](http://api.ai) in creating a Conversation Action include Natural Language Understanding and grammar expansion, form filling, intent matching, and more.

That said, the Actions on Google platform includes a CLI, client library, and Web Simulator, all of which can be used to develop an Action entirely independent of [API.AI](http://api.ai). To do this you’ll need to build your own Action Package, which describes your Action and expected user grammars, and an endpoint to serve Assistant’s requests and provide responses to your users queries. The CLI can be used to deploy your Action Package directly to Google, and you can host your endpoint on any hosting service you wish. Google recommends App Engine on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: This is what Google calls the Actions SDK. More information can be found here https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/sdk/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I found this explanation from [the official page](https://developers.google.com/actions/building-your-apps) most helpful.

> **API.AI**
>
> Use this option for most use cases. Understanding and parsing natural, human language is a very hard task, and API.AI does all that for you. API.AI also wraps the functionality of the Actions SDK into an easy-to-use web IDE that has conveniences such as generating and deploys action packages for you.
>   It also lets you build conversational experiences once and deploy to many other platforms other than Actions on Google.
>
> **ACTIONS SDK**
>
> Use this option if you have simple actions that have very short conversations with limited user input variability. These type of actions typically don't require robust language understanding and typically accomplish one quick use case.
>
> In addition, if you already have an NLU that you want to use and just want to receive raw text and pass it to your own NLU, you will also need to use the Actions SDK.
>
> Finally, the Actions SDK doesn't provide modern conveniences of an IDE, so you have to manually create action packages with a text editor and deploy them to your Google Developer project with a command-line utility.

Answer (score 0):

Google is pushing aggressively everybody to API.AI. The only SDK they have (Node.js) no longer supports expected events for instance. Of course, you don't need to rely on their SDK (you can talk to the API directly) but they may change the API too. So proceed with caution.

Comment: How to talk to the API? Do we have any rest api of sorts?